# C++ - Integer Parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, stringstream

I am struggling with the ['StringStream' problem from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-stringstream/problem?h_r=internal-search). To be precise I am given a string of comma-separated integers, for example "23,4,56" and I need to parse them and return a vector of integers.

I have tried various ways to approach this problem, but they don't work for me.

This is the original code.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector <int> parseInts(string str)
{
    // Function to complete.
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    vector <int> integers = parseInts(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my first idea, conversion with StringStream library.

```
vector <int> parseInts(string str) 
{
    stringstream ss(str); 
    int number;
    // To help with conversion.

    vector <int> temporary;
    // Vector of results.

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        ss >> number;
        temporary.push_back(number);
    }

    return temporary;
}
```

This is my second idea.

```
vector <int> parseInts(string str) 
{
    int number;
    vector <int> temporary;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        number = (str[i]);
        temporary.push_back(number);
    }

    return temporary;
}
```

This is the last idea, I wanted to work on char*.

```
vector <int> parseInts(string str)
{
    char* characters;
    strcpy(characters, str.c_str());
    int numbers;
    vector <int> temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        numbers = stoi(characters);
        temp.push_back(numbers);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Apart from the last example they returned some weird numbers. How can I deal with it?

Comment: "some weird numbers" - what are these numbers and how are they weird?

Comment: *I have tried various ways to approach this problem* -- The easiest way is to simply replace the commas with a space and use your first method.  Did you try that?  Replacing the comma with a space is one single line of C++.

Comment: In addition, your first method should be looping with a `while (ss >> number)` loop, not a `for` loop.  And don't even think about your last method -- that just falls back to low-level `C` programming, and you're supposed to be using C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your were almost there using your first approach, you need to use [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for separating using comma as delimiter.

```
vector<int> parseInts(string str) 
{
    stringstream ss(str); 
    string token;
    vector<int> v;
    while (getline(ss, token, ',')) {
        int x = stoi(token);
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Here's the link where I tested it: https://ideone.com/JGOpS1

Answer (score 2):

In your last approach you forgot to iterate over `characters`. You basically `str.length()` times call `stoi("23,4,56")`. This is the main source of undefined behaviour and some weird numbers.

Hackerrank problems have [useful discussion section](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-stringstream/forum). You can find there plenty of ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << str;
vector<int> res;
while (ss) {
    int n;
    ss >> n;
    res.push_back(n);
    char c;
    ss >> c;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this

```
vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
// Complete this function
stringstream ss(str);
string token;
vector<int> integers;
while(getline(ss,token,',')){
    integers.push_back(stoi(token));
}
return integers;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and the already accepted answer?